# Exporting face-vertex mesh to STL

Tags: matlab, mesh, triangulation

I'm trying to add thickness to a gyroid mesh and export this to STL. I can successfully plot the thickened gyroid mesh as shown below, but this is because I wrote a function to remove undesirable faces, namely, faces which have edges longer than a certain limit. I should also mention that all faces are triangular, so both the vertices and faces matrices are in N x 3 form.

[image: thickened gyroid]

Here's the code which checks for edge lengths and removes those which are `too_long`:

```
function [F] = remove_bad_faces(F,V,too_long)

%% Initiate various counters/storage matrices

bad_face_count = 0;     % Number of bad faces
bad_faces = [];         % Matrix of bad faces
bad_vertices = [];      % Matrix of bad vertices
bad_face_indexes = [];  % Matrix of bad face row indices. I know that the plural of index is not indexes.

%% Find all bad faces

for i=1:size(F,1)

   face = F(i,:);
   v1 = V(face(1),:);
   v2 = V(face(2),:);
   v3 = V(face(3),:);

   if norm(v1-v2) >= too_long || norm(v2-v3) >= too_long || norm(v1-v3) >= too_long
       bad_face_count = bad_face_count + 1;
       bad_faces = [bad_faces; face];
       bad_vertices = [bad_vertices;v1;v2;v3];
       bad_face_indexes = [bad_face_indexes,i];
   end

end

%% Remove bad faces

for j=1:size(bad_face_indexes,2)
   index = bad_face_indexes(j);
   F(index,:) = nan;
end

end
```

As you can see, I'm replacing "bad faces" (i.e. rows of the F matrix) with `NaN`, but this only works for visualisation. When I try to pass the resultant faces and vertices to an STL generating function (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20922-stlwrite-write-ascii-or-binary-stl-files)), I get the following error:

```
Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in stlwrite (line 76)
facets = reshape(facets(:,faces'), 3, 3, []);

Error in Gyroid_Mesh_Script (line 60)
stlwrite('gyroid_test.stl', F, V)
```

So clearly the `NaN` is the problem, and I've tried swapping it with `[]` and `0`, but neither has worked. Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit:
When I use `[]` instead of `NaN`, I *can* export to STL, but it includes these "bad faces", shown below (zoomed-in view):

[image: bad faces]

Comment: 1. I would stick with `[]` instead of `NaN` or `0`.  The offensive facets will simply disappear if you do that.  Is the error the same?
2. The function is complaining that `faces` has some non-positive || non-logical values.  `faces` is an index, so that makes sense.  Does `F` have any negative values?

Some asides:
1. You could move your `bad_face_count` to outside the for-loop, simply assigning it as `bad_face_count=numel(bad_face_indexes);`
2. When you cull `F`, a simpler and more easily understood operation is `F(bad_face_indexes, :) = [];`, not requiring a for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @benJephunneh's response! That fixed everything. I'm posting the updated function which removes faces whose edges are `too_long`:

```
function [F] = remove_bad_faces(F,V,too_long)

%% Initiate various counters/storage matrices

bad_faces = [];         % Matrix of bad faces
bad_vertices = [];      % Matrix of bad vertices
bad_face_indexes = [];  % Matrix of bad face row indices. I know that the plural of index is not indexes.

%% Find all bad faces

for i=1:size(F,1)

   face = F(i,:);
   v1 = V(face(1),:);
   v2 = V(face(2),:);
   v3 = V(face(3),:);

   if norm(v1-v2) >= too_long || norm(v2-v3) >= too_long || norm(v1-v3) >= too_long
       bad_faces = [bad_faces; face];
       bad_vertices = [bad_vertices;v1;v2;v3];
       bad_face_indexes = [bad_face_indexes,i];
   end

end

bad_face_count = numel(bad_face_indexes);

%% Remove bad faces

F(bad_face_indexes,:) = [];

end
```

It also successfully exports to STL using `stlwrite('gyroid_test.stl', F, V)`